# How to get a Vaadin Image from its DOM id

Tags: image, dom, vaadin

I'am trying to set a loading image when a search is running in a vaadin TextField component.

I extended a TextField component in order to implement the client side. Now when a key is up, the loading image is created in the DOM and displayed after the TextField. But now at the end of my search (on the server side), I want to remove the loading image from the DOM but I don't know how to get this image from the DOM with its ID in Vaadin...

On the client side, the code to create the image is :

```
com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element loadingImageElement = DOM.createImg();
loadingImageElement.setAttribute("src", "VAADIN/themes/mytheme/img/ajax-loader.gif");
loadingImageElement.setId("loadingImageId");
```

And on the server side, I want to get the image from its DOM ID but this doesn't work :

```
Element loadingImage = DOM.getElementById("loadingImageId");
if (loadingImage != null) {
    loadingImage.removeFromParent();
}
```

If I use com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element it throws :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element
```

If I use com.google.gwt.user.client.Element (deprecated) it throws :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM
```

I would be thankful for any help !

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: When you add the loading image to the dom, just get hold of that ID (or set one)

Comment: It is already what I do. I put some code above to be more accurate.

Comment: In your extended VTextField, could you store the Element as a field and have a removeLoadingImage() method, which would remove the loadingImage from the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it with :

```
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("$(\"#loadingImageId\").remove()");
```